# I have yamaha mt 15 bs6.My bikes turns off and turns on the digital display when I give ignition and some times doesn't turns on when I give ignition

Tags: yamaha

I have yamaha mt 15 which is not been even a year now now I'm facing serious issues of display going black and turn on again whenever i turn the bike off and some times the bike doesn't turn on when I give ignition its jus does the turn on sound and stays like tht. Yamaha service center person told me it's a battery problem but I don't feel it's a battery issue. Can some body help me resolving this by guiding me wht to do

Comment: If it is less than a year old it is under warranty?

Comment: let the service centre do it under warranty. if you play with it you could invalidate the warranty.

Comment: Yes Ik tht but I couldn't rely on the service center that I have nearby it's shitty it doesn't even know how to service the bike

Comment: Take the bike to an indepedent engineer for another opinion.